# How to assign an instance of a database to Android user

Tags: php, android, mysql, database-design

I am sure this question has been answered but I can't figure out the keywords to find the solution.  I am trying to publish my first app.  I would like each user to have access to his/her own instance of the mySQL database.  I am querying the database through .php scripts.  How may each person that downloads the app have access to his/her own instance of the database.  Users should not be allowed to view other users information.  [User Assigned Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD5I3.jpg)

Should I create an instance of the database upon successful registration?  If so, how do I create a database upon successful registration and how would I assign that database to the user?

Comment: Why would you do that?  That would be an extremely unusual and not very efficient way to do data storage.  The normal way is to provide authentication and authorization functions and filter results by account.  Your idea won't scale whatsoever.

Comment: Yes @GabeSechan is right. it's not the right way to create application with lots of Databases. But if you still has that requirement then check my answer.

Comment: @GabeSechan I appreciate you and Prakash Tank for responding. Your response has helped me refine my search.  This site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api provides a basic understanding of authentication and authorization functions.  
However, let's assume there exist a PurchaseHistoryTable and there are multiple users with separate purchase histories, please provide a resource I can use or an example to follow to learn how a user may only access his/her individual purchase history.

Comment: It appears an application like Firebase would solve the authentication and authorization problem.  Would it allow each user to store his/her own data?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
///after your registration process////
$your_db_name = "new_db";
$link = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", '');

/* check connection */
// if (mysql_select_db()) {
if (!$link->select_db($your_db_name )){
    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE ".$your_db_name;
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        echo "Database created successfully";
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
    exit();
}
else{
    echo "Database already exists";
}

$link->close();
die;
?>
```

So here i am checking that whether the database is already exists or not if not then it will create a new one.